# Multiple swaps from different roles

Tags: werewolv.es

On a somewhat similar note to an earlier question, what is the order of swaps if multiple different roles try to swap with the same target?

For example, a Voodoo doctor and a shapeshifter both kill and shift the same target. Where does everyone end up? What if the zombie is already in the graveyard when the zombify attempt is happening?

Known potential role swapping: Shapeshifter, Skinchanger, Voodoo Doctor, Necromancer, Revenant, Djinn, Vamp (revive)

Also, I think there was an item that worked like a necro? Where would that fit if there was an order of resolution

Comment: I keep coming to this question thinking I'm going to answer it, but whenever I delve into it, it begins to scare the bejesus out of me...

I'm not sure there is a logical, consistent answer to it at the moment!